# issue on import psutil inside python script

Tags: python, linux, centos

i'm not able to import psutil inside my scripts. But the library is installed on my machine.

my library is inside this directory, ***on which there is also simplejson library***:

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil
```

But if i create a script for example this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import psutil
import simplejson as json



print("Hello, world!")
```

i get this errors:

```
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import psutil
ImportError: No module named psutil
```

**UPDATE**

launching `pip install psutil` i got this:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Comment: I had the same error message on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. In my case, the reason was that I was calling my Python files using python3, but my psutil was installed at ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. So, using python2, all was good. I then installed the python3-psutil package using apt install, and can now call psutil using python3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst

Installing using pip on `UNIX`

The easiest way to install `psutil` on `UNIX` is by using `pip` (but first you might need to install python header files; see later). First install `pip`:

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
```

...then run:

```
$ pip install psutil
```

You may need to install `gcc` and python header files first (see later).

Comment: i installed pip and python and header files, but the problem remains

Comment: what is the output of /usr/bin/python --version ?

Comment: weird... well try running pip with --upgrade, m.b. resintalling will help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using *Debian* or a derivative like *Ubuntu*, if you are trying to install `psutil` then `pip` is unnecessary.

There is a system package called `python3-psutil` which can be installed with

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-psutil
```

This should allow all users on your system to reliably import `psutil` from `python3`.